# How to test secured endpoint with silex?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, silex

I found this doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html but the point is that silex's version of `WebTestCase` hasn't `getContainer` so I can't override the `Session`.

I tried the following way:

```
public function createApplication() {
   include __DIR__ . '/../../../../../web/index_dev.php';

   //$app['exception_handler']->disable();
   $app['debug'] = true;
   $app['session.storage'] = $app->share(function() {
            return new MockArraySessionStorage();
   });
   $app['session.test'] = true;

   return $app;
}

public function login() {
   $session = $this->app['session'];

   $firewall = 'admin';
   $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('admin', null, $firewall, array('ROLE_SUPERADMIN'));
   $session->set('_security_' . $firewall, serialize($token));
   $session->save();

   $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
   $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}
```

but test fails with:
`RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/Users/user/Documents/Projects/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php"`

Any ideas?

UPD#1: Providers are loaded in the following way:

```
$app->register(new SessionServiceProvider());
$app['session.storage.options'] = array(
    'name' => $app['sessionOptions']['name'],
    'cookie_lifetime' => $app['sessionOptions']['cookieLifetime'],
    'cookie_domain' => $app['sessionOptions']['cookieDomain']
);
$app['session.storage.handler'] = $app->share(
    function ($app) {
        return new MongoDBSessionHandler(
            $app['mongo.client'],
            array(
                'database' => $app['mongodbOptions']['database'],
                'collection' => $app['mongodbExtraOptions']['sessionCollection'],
            )
        );
    }
);
```

UPD#2:

```
public function testListAction() {
    //$this->logIn();

    $this->client->request('GET', $this->baseUri);

    $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
}
public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->client = parent::createClient();
}
```

Comment: extend KernelTestCase instead.  If Silex doesnt have that (it should, sofar as my thinking goes). Just boot the kernel.  Have a look at [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/307ad07c6157e7d61fefc321d9daa6361164b4e2/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php) for more info

Comment: Can you show the index_dev.php (or wherever you load your providers)?

Comment: Can you show also the full code of your test case (at least the ```setUp``` method and your login test). I fail to see where so you instantiate the ```$this->client``` variable (this is most likely not related to your issue, but anyway...)

Comment: I couldn't see anything wrong so I created a small test app and tried your setup and it works for me. So I'm lost here. My guess is that somehow it does not detect the environment as running from command line it should never give you the error about headers being sent already (in cli mode there's no headers being sent, ever). Can you check if your ```src/Util/Printer.php``` has a white space or a session_start somewhere (or anything that could sent headers)?

Comment: Oh BTW your phrase ```silex's version of WebTestCase hasn't getContainer so I can't override the Session``` is just wrong. Silex's web test case does have the container as a variable class in the ```$this->app``` instance, so there's no need to getContainer as you just call directly ```$this->app``` and you have the container (and you are overriding it Session parameters in your ```createApplication``` method :-)

Comment: Well, thanks for your review)) BTW I noticed that I receive that error (headers being sent..) every time serverside's endpoint tries to get something from `app['Session']`..

Comment: The exception throws error from `NativeSessionStorage`: `RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/Users/user/Documents/Projects/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php" at line 134.

/Users/user/Documents/Projects/project/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php:134
/Users/user/Documents/Projects/project/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php:258`